# Consider the function, f and its second derivative:

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=\frac{4x^2}{x^2+3} $$
$$f'(x)=\frac{24x}{(x^2+3)^2} $$
$$f''(x)=\frac{72(1-x^2)}{(x^2+3)}$$

a)What are the critical numbers(if any)?

b)On what intervals is the function increasing and on what intervals is the function decreasing?

c)What are the inflection points (if any)?

d) On what intervals is the function concave up and on what intervals function concave down?

Any help please I know for problem a you have to set the function to 0 but is it on the first derivative?

Comment: Put text between dollar signs for it to render as math notation, like this: $f(x)=...$

Answer (score 1):

The key is knowing the definitions of numbers.  What is a critical point?  A simple google search will answer this.  The answer is, a critical point is any point where the derivative is zero.

What does it mean for a function to be increasing?  decreasing?  A function is increasing means its derivative is positive.  So you have to find all the values of $x$ where $f(x)>0$.

What is an inflection point?  An inflection point of a function is a point where the second derivative changes from positive to negative or from negative to positive.

What does it mean for a function to be concave up?  It means that the second derivative is positive.